# does ubuntu 18.04 comes with xrdp?

Tags: 18.04, remote-access, xrdp

Hello Ubuntu Community,

> I am looking to control my Ubuntu machine with a windows pc from work.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rdp shows free freerdp-x11  (for x11) & freerdp2-wayland (if using wayland).

Comment: No, it does not. :~)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/xrdp - I haven't used it since 7+ years, but the OP asked about xrdp?

Comment: what do you mean @mikewhatever ?  that it must be added? (via 'universe' of course which the link I provided showed [though would be missed by newbie])

Comment: @guiverc I mean it is not preinstalled, which is another way of saying Ubuntu does not come with xrdp.

Comment: xrdp worked great with a Windows system when ubuntu was at 14.04 and again at 16.04.  After an upgrade to 18.04 I am currently unable to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu

A search via https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rdp  shows

Package **freerdp-x11** *for RDP client for Windows Terminal Services (X11 client)*

and

Package **freerdp2-wayland** *for RDP client for Windows Terminal Services (wayland client)*

*Note: neither come installed by default, but must be installed from 'universe', universe needing to be enabled before use also.*

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 18.04 has **xrdp** in its repository (universe).

The actual version is  **0.9.5-2** (as on July 2018)

You have to activate the **universe** software, by opening **software**, then click on the menu **software/updates**. On the **Ubuntu Software** enable **Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)**. Enter your password if asked for.

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install xrdp xorgxrdp
```